# Custom Caret for each client on real-time connection

Tags: javascript, tinymce, signalr

I have a tinyMCE editor with a SignalR Connection. Right now I am writing and formatting text on one client and receiving text on the other client in real-time with the use of SignalR. Now what I need to do is give a separate caret to each of the clients so that all clients sharing the same document can edit at the same time (same concept of Google Docs - separate cursors with the user's name or a specific color associated with the user). I am stuck on what to look for to be able to do this. Anybody has some useful links that I can look into?

**EDIT:** I have now looked through all the methods in tinyMCE and SignalR and noticed that there are no easy methods for this. After some thinking I came up with the idea to implement a custom caret myself. i.e. use a UNICODE character like | and place it at position 0 when a client opens a document. I need to give this character the behavior of a normal writing caret i.e. keep at the end of the text and move to a position upon clicking a certain area in the document. Do you guys think it is a good idea?

Comment: how will you decide which Caret belongs to which user?

Comment: maybe give a different color to a new caret? and associate it with the user ? example green for user 1 and red for user 2 etc.. ?

Comment: in this case you don't a single special character added and will need to add a wrapping html element too

Comment: yes I started implementing this and I am using span as a wrapping html element. I am finding problems to position the caret according to mouse clicks on the screen and left or right arrow presses etc though

Comment: ok, this will work - there are many funtions out there (the net) on howto handle caret movements